# Is there a way to write multiple awk commands on a single line?

Tags: awk

Is there a clear method to write the following with pipes avoiding the temp file(s) redirection?

```
awk '{gsub("Sat ", "Sat. ");print}' Sat.txt >win.txt
awk '{gsub(" 1-0", "");print}' win.txt >loss.txt
awk '{gsub(" 0-1", "");print}' loss.txt >draw.txt
awk '{gsub(" 1/2-1/2", "");print}' draw.txt >$TARGET
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many `gsub()` as you want in `awk`. Each one of them will replace `$0`, so every time you will be working with the modified string.

However, note you can compress the `gsub()` into just two of them by using some regular expressions:

```
awk '{gsub("Sat ", "Sat. "); gsub(/ (1-0|0-1|1\/2-1\/2)/, "")}1' file
#                                    ^^^ ^^^ ^^^^^^^^^
#                                    1-0 0-1  1/2-1/2
```

The first one replaces `Sat` with `Sat.` and the second one removes space + either of `1-0`, `0-1` or `1/2-1/2`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello Sat is now and 1-0 occurs there when 0-1 results happen but 1/2-1/2 also
bye
$ awk '{gsub("Sat ", "Sat. "); gsub(/ (1-0|0-1|1\/2-1\/2)/, "")}1' file
hello Sat. is now and occurs there when results happen but also
bye
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using semicolon ;
Below code is also use to find out the particular paragraph which contain Sub and Warning and saving into new sub.txt

For Example :-

```
awk '/Sub/' RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" IMD.txt >sub.txt ; awk '/Warning/' RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" IMD.txt >> sub.txt
```